# Why is `this.props.children` not an array when there's just one child?

Tags: reactjs

From a design standpoint, I don't understand why `this.props.children` isn't an array by default. It makes it more difficult to work with when you have to take account that it may sometimes be a single child and sometimes an array.

I understand that using `React.Children` methods allow you to manipulation a components children in much the same way, but it seems like it would be easier to just make `this.props.children` always an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [post](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/751#issuecomment-31509783) on this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/751) answers your question:

> The fact that it's sometimes a single child and sometimes an array is just a perf optimization. Semantically they're equivalent and we
>   could easily just wrap the single child in an array if that was the
>   only issue.
>
> The real issue has to do with nested fragments.
>
> ```
> var a = <Foo />;
> var b = <Foo />;
> var earlierDefinedSet = { a, b };
> <Foo>
>   <Prefix />
>   {this.props.dataList}
>   <Infix />
>   {this.props.children}
>   <Suffix />
>   {earlierDefinedSet}
> </Foo>
> ```
>
> We want the ability to conveniently be able to prepend and concatenate
>   sets of components. You can't just flatten one of these to an array,
>   because you would lose the key context. The keys can only be
>   guaranteed to be unique in the set where they were originally passed
>   in. Not in a concatenated set...

I suggest you checkout the rest of the post/thread.

Comment: Thanks, both your answer and the linked thread give a lot of insight. I knew the React developers wouldn't make such a decision without good reason.